# java hw. Abstract class with a running cash reserve, cash always returning to initialized number

Tags: java, static-members

I have an abstract class called Food where I initialize a double currentCash to 59. I have 2 subclasses of Food; Fruit and Meat where I subtract the price the user types in from my cash reserves of 59. After the user types in a price, then proceeds to the next Food object, whether its a Fruit or Meat type, the cash reserve returns to 59 again.

```
 abstract public class Food implements Interface {//abstract class. 

 static public double currentCash=59;
 double newCash=0; 
 }



public class Fruit extends Food implements Interface {



public  String name;
public  double price;
public  String setName;
public  int priority;



public Fruit() {

    name="no name yet.";
    price=0;
    priority=0;
    realPrice=0;
}

public Fruit(String initialName, int initialPriority, double initalPrice, double initalrealPrice){
    name=initialName;
    priority=initialPriority;
    price=initalPrice;
    realPrice=initalrealPrice;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}


public void setPriority(int priority) {
    if (priority > 0 && priority <= 7) {

        this.priority = priority;
    } else {

        System.err.println("Error, enter 1 through 7"); 

    }
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setrealPrice(double realPrice){
    this.realPrice=realPrice;
}

@Override
public void writeOutput(){

    System.out.println ("Name: "+getName()+" Priority: "+priority +" Price: "+price );



}
public boolean hasSameName (Fruit otherFruit){
    return this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherFruit.name);
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price=price;

}

public double getPrice(){
return price;

}

public double realPrice(){
    return realPrice;
}
@Override
public String eatable() {
    String eatablePrint= "Interface eatable";
    return eatablePrint;
}



@Override
public void cashReserves() {



    newCash= currentCash-price;

    if (newCash>0){
        System.out.println("You have "+newCash+" dollars left for your list.\n");
    }
    else 
    {
    String k = "out of cash";
        System.out.println(k);


    }

    currentCash=newCash;

    }

@Override
public void realPrices() {

    double realCash;
    realCash=currentCash-realPrice;// the price you want to pay is what you type in, but the actual price is here. 
    System.out.println("The grocery store price is " +realPrice+" dollars, and you have "+ realCash+" dollars left.\n");
    if (realCash<10){
    System.out.println("You're running out of real cash");
    }

    if (realCash<=0){
        System.out.println("You're out of real cash");
    }

}
```

}

After each of these cashReserves methods, currentCash returns to 59 again, not the new value after user types in a price.

You entered yes

what kind of apple

mac

enter priority

1

enter price you want to pay

1

Type of apple : mac

Apple's Price you want to pay : 1.0 dollars.

You have 58.0 dollars left for your list.

Comment: Where's the code in which you modify the value of `currentCash`?

Comment: Let's start with the simple stuff: You should not represent money with a float or double. Either use BigDecimal or int/long.

Comment: Where's the code in which you declare and give values to `newCash` and `price`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `cashReserves()` never modifies the value of `currentCash`.

You have a commented out line, `//currentCash=newCash;` which would modify the value of `currentCash`, but... it's commented out.

---

EDIT: Given the current edit to the original question, in which you've uncommented the line in question and moved it out of the `else` block, I can only guess that the value of your `price` variable isn't properly set.  It doesn't matter what `newCash` is set to.  If `price` is `0`, then the line:

```
newCash = currentCash - price;
```

is the same as

```
newCash = currentCash - 0;
```

or just

```
newCash = currentCash;
```

So later in your method when you do:

```
currentCash = newCash;
```

And expect `currentCash` to have changed (and are claiming it's "resetting"), your problem is actually that you simply aren't ever changing the value of `currentCash`.  It doesn't matter what `newCash` was before you called this method.  If `price` is `0`, your method sets `newCash = currentCash`, then you set `currentCash = newCash`... which is the same as just saying `currentCash = currentCash` so it just stays at `59`.

---

EDIT2: Per another edit of the answer... my suspicions in edit1 were exactly correct.  You have:

```
price=0;
```

In your constructor.

```
newCash = currentCash /*59*/ - price /*0*/;
//newCash = 59

currentCash = newCash /*59*/;
//currentCash = 59
```

Nothing is resetting.  You're just never changing the value of `currentCash`.

Perhaps you're taking user input in another class and need to use that to set `price`.  In this case, you need to create a `setter` for `price`:

```
public void setPrice(double newPrice) {
    price = newPrice;
}
```

Or let `cashReserves` set `price` (the former would be preferable to the latter, I think).

```
public void cashReserves(double newPrice) {
    price = newPrice;
    //do everything else your cashReserves method is currently doing
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but doesnt work, so I commented it out.

Comment: Define "doesnt work"?  And I'm not suggesting that uncommenting the line will produce the result that you want, just that this commented line is the only line which would even modify your `currentCash` value.

Comment: It does work. I suspect the problem is that it's inside the `else { }` block, which is never reached unless `newCash <= 0`.

Comment: Where is `price` initialized?  If `price = 0`, then `newCash = currentCash - price` means `newCash = currentCash - 0`, so `currentCash = newCash` effectively does nothing, since you already assigned it the other way...  EDIT: And if `newCash > 0`, then you never go in to `currentCash = newCash` anyway because you execute the `if`, not the `else`.

Comment: actually still doesnt work. Still resets to 59

Comment: @user2803251 We can't guess at what is wrong with your code.  You have to edit the original question to include the changes you've made.  And while you're doing that, please include the lines of code for which you initialize `newCash` and `price` because these are absolutely crucial to the functionality of your code and you're not showing that to us.

Comment: And as a note, unless you're using breakpoints and stepping through your program step by step and seeing the value of `currentCash` change to something else and then resetting to 59, I'm going to bet that nothing is resetting, it's just not being changed at all.

Comment: In included my setter and getter for price. I tested it by printing out my getPrice which is what the user types in, however, when I go to the next Food object on my list and have the user type in at price, again, currentCash goes back to 59.

Comment: But dont you want to have default constructor price as set as 0? Then user types in the price?

Comment: Use a debugger or print the values every step of the way.  Until you can demonstrate that you've actually changed the value of `currentCash`, you can't claim it's "resetting".  You have nothing that demonstrates you're properly changing it's value.

Comment: I seem to have had a problem with a another class. I was trying to solve this problem with another solution (hardwiring prices into the code), and after deleting that area from my code, it seems to work now. I will accept your answer though and thank you.

Comment: @user2803251 Always build and test one class at a time.  Don't integrate the classes until you've tested them individually.

Comment: thank you for the input and following up on the edits I made.

Answer (score 1):

How you are taking price as input?

or

You can try your code like this as well

```
currentCash= currentCash-price;
```

No need to define a new variable to store the difference value.

Comment: the user types it in main using:

(Fruit)Object.setPrice(keyboard.nextDouble());

Comment: The way you are taking input is fine and the currentCash is also defined as static that means whenever it get modified by any object it will reflect the changes value in future use of it. 
Better you use curentCash = currentCash - price